# Why/how does joining arrays with + in PHP work?

Tags: php, arrays

I've noticed recently in PHP you can do this.

```
$myNewArray = $oldArray + $someArray;
```

This looks completely different to anything I've seen before involving manipulating arrays in PHP.

How and why does it work? Are there any pitfalls?

I have recently started using it in some places where I may have used `array_unshift()` and `array_merge()`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When in doubt, [consult the documentation](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php). The behavior is different from array_merge: array_merge appends/overwrites, `+` only appends.

Example:

```
<?php
$a = Array('foo'=>'bar','baz'=>'quux');
$b = Array('foo'=>'something else','xyzzy'=>'aaaa');

$c = $a + $b;
$d = array_merge($a,$b);

print_r($c);
print_r($d);
```

Output - as you see, array_merge overwrote the value from $a['foo'] with $b['foo']; $a+$b did not:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [baz] => quux
    [xyzzy] => aaaa
)
Array
(
    [foo] => something else
    [baz] => quux
    [xyzzy] => aaaa
)
```

Comment: +1, good example, which is pretty much the same situation I was in today earlier.

Answer (score 2):

An operation is defined in the compiler for `+` when both operands are arrays. It does the intuitive operation of joining them.

Comment: +1 for the internal implementation, which I was interested in.

Answer (score 1):

One of the pitfalls is what happens when one of the variables is not an array.

array_merge:

```
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in ...
```

+-operator:

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in ...
```

Comment: Could this be solved like so: `$myNewArray = (array) $oldArray + (array) $someArray;` ?